# Angular prepopulate form for item update

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, rest

**NodeJS get by id**

NodeJs service for item retrieval.

```
 const getById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myId = await Inventory.findById(req.params.id).exec();
    res.json(myId);
  } catch (error) {
     res.json({ message: error });
  }
 };
```

**Update nodejs**

NodeJS service for item update

```
const updateInventory = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const edit = await Inventory.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                CategoryName: req.body.CategoryName,
                Description: req.body.Description,
                Quantity: req.body.Quantity,
                InStock: req.body.InStock,
                DateReceived: req.body.DateReceived,
            },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.json(edit);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error });
    }
};
```

**Angular service**

Angular service for item retrieval and update.

```
getById(id: number): Observable<Inventory> {
     return this.http.get<Inventory>(this.baseUrl + '/detail/'+ id, this.headerOptions)
        .pipe(
       catchError(this.errorHandler)
    );
}
update(id: number, inventory: Inventory): Observable < Inventory > {
     return this.http.put<Inventory>(this.baseUrl + 'edit/'+ id, inventory, this.headerOptions)
     .pipe(
       catchError(this.errorHandler)
    );
}
```

How can I prepopulate form with `Inventory Item` data for the further update with the Angular service?